# creating a dictionary from a nested list containing dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
[{'duration': 634, 'risetime': 1586496046}, 
 {'duration': 473, 'risetime': 1586501927}, 
 {'duration': 608, 'risetime': 1586537843}, 
 {'duration': 536, 'risetime': 1586543678}, 
 {'duration': 577, 'risetime': 1586579648}]
```

I want to create one dictionary from this list of dictionaries in python i.e {'duration': [634, 473, 608, 536, 577],'risetime': [1586496046, 1586501927, 1586537843, 1586543678, 1586579648]}

Comment: What would that dictionary look like?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour]. What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. See [ask] for advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[{'duration': 634, 'risetime': 1586496046}, 
  {'duration': 473, 'risetime': 1586501927}, 
  {'duration': 608, 'risetime': 1586537843}, 
  {'duration': 536, 'risetime': 1586543678}, 
  {'duration': 577, 'risetime': 1586579648}]

#Initializing an empty dict
b = {'duration':[],'risetime':[]}
#looping through all values of list 'a' & appending values to respective keys in 'b'
for x in a:
    b['duration'].append(x['duration'])
    b['risetime'].append(x['risetime'])
```

If you are looking for such an output: {'duration': [634, 473, 608, 536, 577],
 'risetime': [1586496046, 1586501927, 1586537843, 1586543678, 1586579648]}

Answer (score 0):

This is a good usecase for `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [
    {'duration': 634, 'risetime': 1586496046}, 
    {'duration': 473, 'risetime': 1586501927}, 
    {'duration': 608, 'risetime': 1586537843}, 
    {'duration': 536, 'risetime': 1586543678}, 
    {'duration': 577, 'risetime': 1586579648}
]

d = defaultdict(list)
for x in lst:
    for k, v in x.items():
        d[k].append(v)

print(d)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'duration': [634, 473, 608, 536, 577], 'risetime': [1586496046, 1586501927, 1586537843, 1586543678, 1586579648]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
myList = [{'duration': 634, 'risetime': 1586496046},
 {'duration': 473, 'risetime': 1586501927},
 {'duration': 608, 'risetime': 1586537843},
 {'duration': 536, 'risetime': 1586543678},
 {'duration': 577, 'risetime': 1586579648}]

myDic = {'duration': [], 'risetime':[]}
for x in myList:
    for y in x:
        myDic[y].append(x[y])

print(myDic)
```

output

```
{'duration': [634, 473, 608, 536, 577], 'risetime': [1586496046, 1586501927, 1586537843, 1586543678, 1586579648]}
```